# ForkJoinPool resets thread interrupted state

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent, forkjoinpool

I just noticed the following phenomena when cancelling a Future returned by [ForkJoinPool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html). Given the following example code:

```
ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool();
Future<?> fut = pool.submit(new Callable<Void>() {

  @Override
  public Void call() throws Exception {
    while (true) {
      if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) { // <-- never true
        System.out.println("interrupted");
        throw new InterruptedException();
      }
    }
  }
});

Thread.sleep(1000);
System.out.println("cancel");
fut.cancel(true);
```

The program never prints `interrupted`. The docs of [ForkJoinTask#cancel(boolean)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinTask.html#cancel%28boolean%29) say:

> mayInterruptIfRunning - this value has no effect in the default implementation because interrupts are not used to control cancellation.

If ForkJoinTasks ignore interrupts, how else are you supposed to check for cancellation inside Callables submitted to a ForkJoinPool?

Comment: BTW, why are you using FJP for this case?

Comment: @Mikhail this is just a very minimal example of our use case. We launch some RecursiveActions inside the callable which get invoked on ForkJoinTask.getPool()

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This happens because `Future<?>` is a `ForkJoinTask.AdaptedCallable` which extends `ForkJoinTask`, whose cancel method is:

```
public boolean cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning) {
    return setCompletion(CANCELLED) == CANCELLED;
}

private int setCompletion(int completion) {
    for (int s;;) {
        if ((s = status) < 0)
            return s;
        if (UNSAFE.compareAndSwapInt(this, statusOffset, s, completion)) {
            if (s != 0)
                synchronized (this) { notifyAll(); }
            return completion;
        }
    }
}
```

It does not do any interruptions, it just sets status. I suppose this happens becouse `ForkJoinPools`'s `Future`s might have a very complicated tree structure, and it is unclear in which order to cancel them.

Comment: Thanks Mikhail for your investigation. Looks like there is no way to check for cancellation from within a Callable. I'll need to submit a ForkJoinTask and call isCancelled() on that, which sucks because you always need to pass a around the reference to ForkJoinTask to check for cancellation

Answer (score 1):

Sharing some more light on top of @Mkhail answer:

Using ForkJoinPool execute() instead of submit() will force a failed Runnable to throw a worker exception, and **this exception will be caught** by the Thread UncaughtExceptionHandler.

Taking from Java 8 code:
submit is using AdaptedRunnableAction().
execute is using RunnableExecuteAction() (see the **rethrow(ex)**).

```
 /**
 * Adaptor for Runnables without results
 */
static final class AdaptedRunnableAction extends ForkJoinTask<Void>
    implements RunnableFuture<Void> {
    final Runnable runnable;
    AdaptedRunnableAction(Runnable runnable) {
        if (runnable == null) throw new NullPointerException();
        this.runnable = runnable;
    }
    public final Void getRawResult() { return null; }
    public final void setRawResult(Void v) { }
    public final boolean exec() { runnable.run(); return true; }
    public final void run() { invoke(); }
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5232453952276885070L;
}

/**
 * Adaptor for Runnables in which failure forces worker exception
 */
static final class RunnableExecuteAction extends ForkJoinTask<Void> {
    final Runnable runnable;
    RunnableExecuteAction(Runnable runnable) {
        if (runnable == null) throw new NullPointerException();
        this.runnable = runnable;
    }
    public final Void getRawResult() { return null; }
    public final void setRawResult(Void v) { }
    public final boolean exec() { runnable.run(); return true; }
    void internalPropagateException(Throwable ex) {
        rethrow(ex); // rethrow outside exec() catches.
    }
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5232453952276885070L;
}
```