# In a Java 7+ ForkJoinPool, is it possible to cancel a task and all subtasks?

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent, fork-join

My program searches for a solution (any solution) to a problem through a divide-and-conquer approach, implemented using recursion and `RecursiveTasks`'s: I fork a task for the first branch of the division, then recurse into the second branch: if the second branch has found a solution, then I cancel the first branch, otherwise I wait for its result.

This is perhaps not optimal. One approach would be for any of the launched tasks to throw an exception if a solution is found. But then, how would I cancel all the launched tasks? Does cancelling a task also cancel all sub-tasks?

Comment: http://www.coopsoft.com/ar/CalamityArticle.html

Answer (score 3):

You can use the simple approach with task manager. For example:

```
public class TaskManager<T> {

private List<ForkJoinTask<T>> tasks;

public TaskManager() {
    tasks = new ArrayList<>();
}

public void addTask(ForkJoinTask<T> task) {
    tasks.add(task);
}

public void cancelAllExcludeTask(ForkJoinTask<Integer> cancelTask) {
    for (ForkJoinTask<T> task : tasks) {
        if (task != cancelTask) {
            task.cancel(true);
        }
    }
}

public void cancelTask(ForkJoinTask<Integer> cancelTask) {
    for (ForkJoinTask<T> task : tasks) {
        if (task == cancelTask) {
            task.cancel(true);
        }
    }
}
```

}

And the task:

```
public class YourTask extends RecursiveTask<Integer> {

private TaskManager<Integer> taskManager;

@Override
protected Integer compute() {
        // stuff and fork
        newTask.fork();
        // do not forget to save in managers list
        taskManager.addTask(newTask);

        // another logic

        // if current task should be cancelled            
        taskManager.cancelTasks(this);

        // or if you have decided to cancel all other tasks
        taskManager.cancelAllExcludeTask(this);
}
}
```

Comment: The problem with cancelAllExcludeTask() is that when a task is holding a resource or has some other dependency there may be an internal problem. It comes down to the same problems as Thread.stop(). No framework can know what any task is doing so it is always dangerous to try to stop a task.

Comment: If you should care about allocated resources with task, it is still possible to extend FutureTask directly and override it's cancel() method. And then sumbit such task to executor.

Comment: Are you sure that `RecursiveTask.cancel(true)` really stops the task? Because the `cancel()` implementation in `ForkJoinTask` (from which `RecursiveTask` inherits), simply sets a `cancelled` flag, but does not interrupt the thread. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21320156/forkjoinpool-resets-thread-interrupted-state

Comment: cancel calls setCompletion(int completion) which may issue: synchronized (this) { notifyAll(); } That may have unintended consequences for other tasks and as noted above it does not interrupt the current thread. The only sure/safe way to cancel a task and all its sub-tasks (the original question) is to manually code the logic yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The framework cannot cancel a task for the same reason you cannot cancel a thread. See the documentation on Thread.stop() for all the reasons. What locks could the task be holding? What outside resources could it have linkage to? All the same Thread.stop() reasons apply to tasks as well (after all, tasks run under threads.) You need to tell the task to stop just like you tell a thread to stop.

I manage another fork/join project that uses the scatter-gather technique. The way I do a cancel, or short-circuit, is that every task I create is passed an object (PassObject) that has a

```
protected volatile boolean stop_now = false;
```

and a method for stopping the task

```
protected void stopNow() {stop_now = true; }
```

Each task periodically checks the stop_now and when true it gracefully ends the task.

Unfortunately, the stop_now needs to be volatile since another thread is going to set it. This can add significant overhead if you check it frequently.

How to set this field in another task gets a little tricky. Each task I create also contains a reference to the array of references to every other task

```
int nbr_tasks = nbr_elements / threshold;
// this holds the common class passed to each task
PassObject[] passList = new PassObject[nbr_tasks];
 for (int i = 0; i < nbr_tasks; i++) 
passList[i] = new PassObject( passList,… other parms);
```

Once the list is formed I fork() each object in passList. Each PassObject contains a reference to the array, passList, which contains a reference to every object that is passed to each task. Therefore, every task knows about every other task and when one task want to cancel the others it simply calls the cancelOthers method with a reference to the passList.

```
private void cancelOthers (PassObject[] others) {
// tell all tasks to stop
 for (int i = 0, max = others.length; i < max; i++)
others[i].stopNow();
```

If you’re using Java8 then you can do a form of scatter-gather with the CountedCompler class instead of the RecusiveTask. For Java7 or if you still want to use RecursiveTask, then the first task in the recursion needs to create an AtomicBoolean field (AtomicBoolean stop_now = new AtomicBoolean(false);) and include a reference to this field in every new RecursiveTask it creates. With recursion, you don’t know how many levels of tasks you’ll need in the beginning. 
Again, you’ll need to check for a true in the boolean periodically in your code and when true, end the task gracefully.

The above is just a hint of how you can do a cancel. Every application is different. What I do works for my application – but the logic is the same. You need something common in every task that a task can set and every other task can see.

I'd add more code but the code insert only is taking one line at a time and it isn't practical.

Comment: How so? A race is irrelevant. As long as the only modification is to set false.

Comment: "Each task I create also contains a reference to the array of references to **every other task**." - Wouldn't it be sufficient when every task only knows its direct sub-tasks (e.g. the tasks that it created itself)?

Comment: I use a scatter-gather technique that creates all the tasks necessary in the beginning. This is not a recursive decomposition technique. If you use recursion to create sub-tasks, that create sub-tasks, then you should use the AtomicBoolean method and pass that reference to each sub-task. But, just cancelling one chain of sub-tasks isn't enough. You need to cancell ALL Tasks.

Comment: the convenience with InterruptedException was that if you call 3rd party methods they obey InterruptedException and stop_now could be supported by your code only

Comment: Third party methods do what they want. There is no guarantee that any third party method will obey any standard procedure. This thread is 16 months old, you're a bit late to the party.